# Change objects to soild view

Tags: 3d-view, objects, wireframe

When I download some files from blendswap they look like this.
[image]

I want the silver/gray solid view.

Comment: Make sure the maximum draw type in *Properties > Display* (near the bottom right of your screenshot) is set to at least solid.